# Can't find the paragraph text of a parsed HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML string as part of an error response I would like to parse:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #powered_by {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #traceback {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>400 Bad Request</h2>
        <p>Invalid request format, verify all request parameters</p>
        <pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 628, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 687, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 59, in json_handler
    value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    ...
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (400, 'Invalid request format, verify all request parameters')
</pre>
    <div id="powered_by">
      <span>
        Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 18.1.0</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
"
```

In my JavaScript, I'm creating a JQuery object of the text above (present in a variable `responseText`) which should then allow me to search it:

```
var responseHTML = $(responseText);
```

I see `responseHTML` is a list of objects identified by the HTML tags, each with properties to access their respective text. I then try to search `responseHTML` using `.find()` but it always returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
var paragraphText = responseHTML.find('p:first').innerText;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the `<!DOCTYPE..` string first to parse it with jQuery. Then when you've used `$('<html><head>...')` on the string you'll see that you've selected every node in the body. The `<p>` tag is the 9nth node.

But you have tools to do this stuff:

You can turn a string of HTML into a new document with the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) interface. Create a new instance and use the `parseFromString` method with the `text/html` mimeType.

It will return a new `document` instance where you can use `querySelector` to fin the first occurence of your `<p>` tag.

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #powered_by {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #traceback {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>400 Bad Request</h2>
        <p>Invalid request format, verify all request parameters</p>
        <pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 628, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 687, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 59, in json_handler
    value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    ...
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (400, 'Invalid request format, verify all request parameters')
</pre>
    <div id="powered_by">
      <span>
        Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 18.1.0</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
`
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
const text = doc.querySelector('p').innerText;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(htmlContent) is only parsing the content of  and  and returns a list of top elements.

You can use `p.filter('p')[0].innerText` to access the paragraph since it's a direct child of

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var str = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta><title>400 Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">#powered_by {margin-top: 20px;border-top: 2px solid black;font-style: italic;}#traceback {color: red;}</style></head><body><h2>400 Bad Request</h2><p>Invalid request format, verify all request parameters</p><pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 628, in respondself._do_respond(path_info) File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 687, in _do_respond response.body = self.handler() File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 219, in __call__ self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs) File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 59, in json_handler value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs) File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 54, in __call__ return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs) ... cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (400, "Invalid request format, verify all request parameters")</pre> <div id="powered_by"> <span> Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 18.1.0</a> </span> </div> </body></html>'


var res = str.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf("<p>") + 3, 
    str.lastIndexOf("</p>")
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: OP receives the HTML as a string, so there is no `document` to look in.

Comment: Thank you, Emiel! I also added a string search option.